# Synchronisation between IE for Modern UI and IE for Desktop

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, modern-ui

I've heard from various sources that some things are inconsistent between the desktop and metro versions of IE in terms of remembering open tabs, preferences etc.

Where a feature exists in both, what is synchronised between the two and what isn't?

Comment: Have you verified this is actually a problem?  Windows 8 has not been released to retail at this, I would simply try it yourself, figure it out yourself.

Comment: I've not tried it myself, but have read articles that point out possible sources of confusion. This one being the main one I can find now: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/10/02/paul_allen_windows_8/

Comment: @GeogrgeDuckett - Come back when you have verified it is even a problem. If you read the article is based on a "review" of the preview version of Windows 8. The article you found is just click bait.

Comment: I can confirm this. The metro app and the desktop app operate as two seperate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the feature differences. (As far as I know, there aren't any feature differences except for the obvious UI changes, and the sandboxing/security things that the majority of users won't have to worry about.) But, regarding the "synchronization" between the two:

- Configuration settings that affect the entire system, like Connection settings, are the same for both
- Configuration settings that affect only Internet Explorer, like Tab preferences, cookies, or which tabs were open in a session, are not synchronized between the two

Generally I suggest choosing one, and using it consistently. If you know the Windows 8 gestures and/or have a touch screen, I suggest the RT version. But if you are in Desktop mode most of the time anyway, maybe the old, desktop UI would be a better choice.

(Remember, you can dock the "RT" version so it doesn't stay full screen. So that shouldn't be a significant reason to choose one over the other.)